# How do I dissolve a render into it's components?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, glare

[image]
This first image has a wireframe box with an emission shader. It is placed at the same location as a metallic cube. If I were to use the glare node in the compositor, I would get glare from metallic reflections and maybe from ambient light.
I would instead like the glare to only source from the emission shaders in the scene.
I have tried this with Viewlayers but it is a little overkill for something that I suppose is possible in the compositor. I picture there being a way to take just the emission pass and connect it to the glare node.
I picture the compositor setup looking something like this, even though I just faked it by renaming a *value* node here.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question, because in order to edit the emission pass, you need to output the pass so you can be able to use it in the compositor. You might need to explain why the emission pass is not working for you

Comment: How do I output the emission pass automatically? I don't want to run a separate render when the emission pass may already be accessible in a node of some kind

Comment: You just need to activade the passes that you want, it's inside the right properties panel > view layer > "THE PASS THAT YOU NEED. after that, the pass will be render with the main beauty pass and it will be accessible on the compositor

Comment: @Emir. Thanks! I never use that panel but now I see what you mean. I'm trying it now. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can output the passes of the render so you can use them with the compositor tool, in this case, the Emission pass.

[image]

You just need to go to View Layer > Light > Emission

[image]

Once you select that, you can render your scene.

Inside the compositor, select the Emission socket and edit your emission only, in this case i used a glare node.

[image]

And finally, you can combine that on top of your beauty pass with a mix node.

[image]

Make sure to connect the mix node socket to the composite node so you can render again to get the final result